# Send POST data without form to another server

Tags: php, post, data-transfer

My server does not support json_encode or json_decode, I am wanting to send a 2D array to a different server using `serialize()`, then process it and print it a json encoded array. I'm afraid that the limitations of GET would not allow for longer arrays. How can I do this?

Comment: Check out [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: it would be far better to get the json functions available on your server.  this seems like a less than ideal solution.

Comment: I've looked into it but PECL seems to strenuous to set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't upgrade PHP to get the built-in JSON functions, use a PHP implementation of JSON encoding, such as [this](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson-php/source/browse/trunk/simplejson.php) (found through a quick search; there may be better implementations).

Or use POST (through libcurl, as others have noted) if your GET parameters are long.

Comment: I think I found that somewhere before but didn't think it would be as robust as I would need. Thanks, works like a charm!